# Why look and shake your gun after ammo runs out?

Tags: action

This has always amused me. A lot of times, while in the heat of battle, after the gun ammo runs out, the character looks at his gun giving it a slight shake. As if thinking this will fix a possible jam or add more ammo to it. What kind of reaction is that and why is it used so frequently?

I have just been watching another episode of Lost, and Sawyer did this exact thing when he ran out of ammo shooting at the 'others'.

Comment: It's the cinematic equivalent of wandering round the kitchen, making scissor motions with your fingers, in the vain hope it will make the scissors easier to find...

Comment: My favorite though is from Buffy the Vampire Slayer...  In one episode, Vampire-Willow comes over from another dimension and is seen by Xander.  Later when Human-Willow walks in, Xander pulls out a cross and tries to stop her with it.  Not surprisingly the cross doesn't work, so Xander looks at it, shakes it, and tries again.  If shaking a gun seldom works, shaking a wooden cross to get it to work, is even more pointless.

Comment: I can honestly say I've never noticed this and even now that you mention it I can't recall it specifically.

Answer (score 5):

Probably to give the audience a clear indication of what's going on. If the guy said, "Oh, no! I'm out of bullets!" he'd look like an idiot.

Comment: I guess it's the same type of indicator as tapping repeatedly on the phone cradle when the line goes dead - like that would magically reconnect them.

Comment: Or repeatedly pressing the brake pedal when your brakes are out. Or noisily jiggling a doorknob when a door is locked. How many of these are there, I wonder.

Comment: I'm sure tvtropes.org must have a list somewhere, but I can't find it :(

Comment: @John Sensebe I dunno about the others but if my brakes went out and my choice was to accept death or keep trying the brakes... I'd keep trying the brakes.

Comment: @Andrew, but I don't know that pumping the pedal is the best strategy. Maybe a question for another Stack Exchange community?

Comment: Well I'd try to divert the car to slow momentum too.  On the highway, for instance, maybe try to use the shoulder bumps to slow down a bit and worst case scenario sideswipe the wall.  WOULD THIS WORK?!

Comment: @Andrew, it might work if you drove the car through a fruit cart or the outdoor seating of a restaurant...